# How to Add a Custom Logo to an ERC-20 Token in Safe Wallet?

Tags: safe-core

I'm looking for guidance on how to incorporate a custom logo for my ERC-20 token when importing it into my Safe Wallet. Currently, the token displays a default logo, and I want to personalize it with the specific logo associated with my token. I've explored the settings within the Safe Wallet but haven't found a direct option to customize the logo for ERC-20 tokens. Additionally, I've reviewed online resources related to ERC-20 token customization but haven't found specific instructions for integrating logos into the Safe Wallet.

Answer (score 0):

We have a process for that! Could you please:

- Provide a proof of legitimacy of the token (links to Coingecko, CoinMarketCap, etc. are accepted).
- Provide the **network** where the token lives.
- Provide the **contract address** for the token to be modified.
- Provide a logo **image** to be attached to the desired token.

Thanks!
Louis